# How do I correctly call passport.js functions with express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to call the passport.authenticate function as response to post request for my registration view. I've been following [this tutorial here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) to get my head around passport.js and express but having completed the first page of instructions and making the necessary changes for express.js 4.0 every page I try to access returns error 500 and displays the following stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Object #<serverResponse> has no method 'authenticate'
    at module.exports (/home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/routes/index.js:66:37)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at /home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/connect-flash/lib/flash.js:21:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /home/myUserName/Desktop/manufacturing/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
```

Here is the code for /routes/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(app, passport) {
  /* GET home page. */
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Home Page'
    });
  });

  /* GET about page */
  router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('about', {
      title: 'About Us'
    });
  });

  /* GET contact page */
  router.get('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('contact', {
      title: 'Contact Us'
    });
  });

  /* GET login page */
  router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', {
      title: 'User Login',
      message: req.flash('loginMessage')
    });
  });

  /* GET register page */
  router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('register', {
      title: 'User Registration',
      message: req.flash('signupMessage')
    });
  });

  /* POST register page */
  router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/',
    failureRedirect : '/register',
    failureFlash    : true
  }));

  /* Log Out */

  router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  /* 404 - page not found */
  router.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('404', {
      title: '404 - Not Found'
    });
  });

  // Route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();
    res.redirect('/');
  };
};
```

And here is my server.js:

```
var express       = require('express');
var path          = require('path');
var logger        = require('morgan');
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var session       = require('express-session');
var passport      = require('passport');
var flash         = require('connect-flash');

// Database

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
require('./config/passport')(passport); 

// Routes
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();

// Express configuration
app.use(logger('dev')); // log every request to console
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
}

// Passport configuration

app.use(session({ secret: 'MySecretHere',
                  saveUninitialized: true,
                  resave: true})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

app.use('/', routes);

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running on ' + port);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your are getting the error is because your exporting a function that takes `app` and `passport` as a parameters for your http handlers, but when your require it in your `server.js` your are not passing `passport` or `app`.

You need to somehow pass `passport` into the require. 
You could change your routes files to 
If your are using the `express.Router`

```
   var router = express.Router();
   module.exports = function(passport) {
       // init your routes with passport and router
       router.post('/' function(req, res) {
          //...
       });
      // make sure to return router in the function though
      return router;
   }
```

If not using `express.Router` you could pass both `app` and `passport` and simply attach handlers to `app`

```
   module.exports = function (app, passport) {
       app.post('/', function(req, res) {
         //...
       });
       // no need to return app
   }
```

then in server.js

```
     // if your using `express.Router()` in routes file
     app.use('/', require('./routes')(passport));
     // If your registering handler on app itself just bootstrap it
     require('./routes')(app, passport);
```

Comment: This answer makes sense, but when I try it npm start fails with the following error: `TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  } has no method 'authenticate'`

Comment: Thats very interesting, I think i may understand whats going on. Try returning the `router` in the exported function in your routes file. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: So im pretty sure it was throwing an error because `app.use` requires an http handler as a parameter, but the routes file wasn't returning the `router` in the exported function.

Comment: Where is `handler` supposed to be defined? Whether I pass both `app` & `passport`, or try to attach handlers to `app` the application fails to reference `handler` in my routes file.

Comment: Sorry that was just for example for how you would register "handlers" for `app` or `router` respectively. `handler` does not need to be defined.

Comment: D'oh, that was pretty stupid of me. I understand it now and it's finally working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass passport to your route. You can do it changing your code this way:

/routes/index.js

from `module.exports = function(app, passport) {...}`

to 
`module.exports = function(passport){ return function(app) {...}}`

/server.js

 from `app.use('/', routes);`

to `app.use('/', routes(passport));`

Comment: Can you explain why it's necessary to return app as a function? When I try making your changes the application starts fine but if I try to load a page it just says "waiting for localhost..." and never gets anywhere. Console doesn't log anything either.

Comment: Next modification should help
module.exports = function(passport){ ... return router; }
You do not need to pass an "app" if you want to include routes from server.js like
app.use('/', routes(passport));